# Replication of Database in PostgreSQL

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.4

I want to Replicate my PostgreSQL, in the website there far too many options, I want to know which one to choose.

I have a main server which the database is stored at. Inserting, editing and deleting or records occurs on this server. The second server contains a replica of the database which accessed only for search.

Which type of replication is this, and which option to choose ?

Comment: That's a simple (streaming) replication: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION If you want to make managing this easier, have a look at http://repmgr.org/

Comment: @OssamaNasser did you get somewhere with it?